# Laravel, Method [...] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

**I have the controller:**

```
class Comments extends Controller 
{
    public function GenerateComments($id)
    {
        $theme = DB::table('New_Themes')
                   ->where('id', $id)
                   ->get();

        $Comments = NewTheme_Comment::where('id_theme',  $id)->get();

        $array = $this->tree($Comments);

        function tree($Comments, $parent_id = 0, $level=0, $c=0) 
        {
            global $var;
            global $array;
            global $m;

            foreach($Comments as $Comment) 
            {
                if ($Comment['parent_id'] == $parent_id) {

                    $m++;

                    $array[$m][0]=$Comment['id'];

                    If ($level > $var)  {$var++; $array[$m][1]=0;} else {  

                        if ($c < 0) $array[$m][1]=$var-$level+1; else {$c--; $array[$m][1]=0;};
                            $var=$level; 
                };

                tree($Comments, $Comment['id'], $level+1,$c);
            }
        };

        return $this->$array;
    };

    return view('comments', ['Themes'=> $theme, 'Comments'=> $Comments, 'Array' => $array]);
}
```

The problem is

> Method [tree] does not exist.

but I don't understand why it appears, if I am calling a function within a function (like that below)

```
$array = $this->tree($Comments);

function tree($Comments, $parent_id = 0, $level=0, $c=0) 
{
    return $this->$array;
}
```

Are there any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: I bet `tree` is not a method -- a method of `$this` class. It's a function -- an anonymous function.

Comment: So what should I do, I tried both these: $array = $this->tree($Comments); and $array = tree($Comments);

Comment: Yeah an anonymous function kind of, first time i'm using this kind of stuff

Comment: Create a method instead  and refactor the code inside it.

Comment: But how can I call a method of class inside a class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling your function `tree` with `$this` which means PHP will look `tree` as a method inside `Comments` class instead of your `GenerateComments` method.

Change

```
$array = $this->tree($Comments);
```

To this

```
$array = tree($Comments);
```

**Note:** You are also defining your function after you are calling it. PHP will look `tree` as it is in the namespace so it'll either won't work. Instead just define your function before you call it. Like so

```
function tree($Comments, $parent_id = 0, $level = 0, $c = 0) {
    // ...
}

$array = tree($Comments);
```

It is also **not recommended** to define your function inside of a function. Instead doing that, just make your `tree` function `a method` inside your controller and use that instead. Like so

```
class Comments extends Controller 
{
    public function GenerateComments() 
    {
        // ...
        $array = $this->tree($comments);
    }

    public function tree($tree) 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It says: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\tree()

Comment: @DomainFlag Which php version you are using?

Comment: 5.6.8 - php version

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `tree` function is inside the controller `GenerateComments` function.

It appears you want to use it as a class method.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the function with `call_user_func` this way:

```
$array = call_user_func('tree', $Comments);
```